# Android how to resole duplicate class , just class not a module

Tags: android, gradle

Android gradle  implementation  A.aar  and  B.aar   ,if  A.aar  contain  **com.aa.A.java**  B.aar contain the same class  **com.aa.A.java** ，then  how  to  resovle  ?  who can tell me ,what should
I do ?

please help , A.aar  B.aar  from differet compay or palce